# My React/Flask app takes my JSON in one route but not the other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, flask

I have this code that works pretty well (frontend isn't figured out but it does its job of registering a user and updating my database)

```
export default class APIService {

  static RegisterUser(username, email, password, base_city, about_me) {
      
    return fetch(`/register`, {
      'method':'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(username, email, password)
    })
    .then(resp => window.location.href = "login")
    .catch(error => console.log(error, "Not In the APIService"))
  }
```

from app.py

```
@app.route("/register", methods=['POST'])
def register():
    username = request.json['username']
    email = request.json['email']
    password = request.json['password']
    base_city = request.json['base_city']
    about_me = request.json['about_me']
    hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password)
    user = User(username=username, email=email, password=hashed_password, base_city=base_city, about_me=about_me)
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
```

The way I understand it is that I pass a bunch of info into the RegisterUser function, it turns it into a JSON, then on the backend it takes that information and uploads it to the database.

In my next function that I'm having problems with, I want to log in the user based on an inputted `username` and `password`:

```
const logitin = async ({ username, password }) => {
            try {
            await fetch(`/userlookup`, {
            method: "POST",
            mode: "cors",
            headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(username, password),
            });
            return console.log('logitin', username, password);
            } catch (error) {
            console.log("error time!", username, password);
            return false;
            }
            };
logitin({username, password})
```

It is my belief that this takes the username and password, makes it into a JSON object and sends it here in my app.py:

```
@app.route("/userlookup", methods=['GET','POST'])
def userlookup():
    username = request.json['username']
    password = request.json['password']
    hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password)
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    print(username)
    if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, password):
        print('youre in')
        login_user(user)
        return username
    else:
        print('tripped')
```

Here I expect it to take the `username` and `password` items from the JSON object and assign them the `username` and `password` variable respectively and eventually check if both of those are in the database.

When I run this, I get this error:

```
  File "/home/ionic_apps/pobblebonk/backend/app.py", line 136, in userlookup
    username = request.json['username']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Which I'm confused by because it seems not to get the `username = request.json['username']` line when I'm using that exact same syntax in the `/register` route and it seems to understand that.  Any idea why this is?

edit:

including full traceback

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021 09:07:47] "POST /userlookup HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ionic_apps/pobblebonk/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ionic_apps/pobblebonk/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/ionic_apps/pobblebonk/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/ionic_apps/pobblebonk/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ionic_apps/pobblebonk/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ionic_apps/pobblebonk/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ionic_apps/pobblebonk/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ionic_apps/pobblebonk/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/ionic_apps/pobblebonk/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ionic_apps/pobblebonk/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ionic_apps/pobblebonk/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ionic_apps/pobblebonk/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ionic_apps/pobblebonk/backend/app.py", line 136, in userlookup
    username = request.json['username']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why your register route is working to be honest but you need to create a single object for your JSON.stringify like below:

```
static RegisterUser(username, email, password, base_city, about_me) {
      
    return fetch(`/register`, {
      'method':'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, email, password })
    })
    .then(resp => window.location.href = "login")
    .catch(error => console.log(error, "Not In the APIService"))
  }
```

and to log in

```
const logitin = async ({ username, password }) => {
            try {
            await fetch(`/userlookup`, {
            method: "POST",
            mode: "cors",
            headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
            });
            return console.log('logitin', username, password);
            } catch (error) {
            console.log("error time!", username, password);
            return false;
            }
            };
logitin({username, password})
```

Otherwise your JSON will be a single string.